# How to escape single quotes in Python on a server to be used in JavaScript on a client

Tags: javascript, python, string, escaping

Consider:

```
>>> sample = "hello'world"
>>> print sample
hello'world
>>> print sample.replace("'","\'")
hello'world
```

In my web application I need to store my Python string with all single quotes escaped for manipulation later in the client browsers JavaScript.  The trouble is Python uses the same backslash escape notation, so the replace operation as detailed above has no effect.

Is there a simple workaround?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use:

```
sample.replace("'", r"\'")
```

or

```
sample.replace("'", "\\'")
```

Comment: This is so wrong! Try this: sample = "\\'"; sample.replace("'", "\\'") #fail!

Comment: `sample.replace("'", r"\'")` works for me.

Comment: That is not wrong. STOP TRUSTING REPL.
```
sample = "hello'world"; print(sample.replace("'", "\\'"))
```

Remember the REPL escapes quotes for you. Actual string might be different. Read __str__ vs __repr__.

Answer (score 63):

As a general solution for passing data from Python to Javascript, consider serializing it with the `json` library (part of the standard library in Python 2.6+).

```
>>> sample = "hello'world"
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps(sample)
"hello\'world"
```

Comment: +1 this safely takes care of backslashes, newlines and Unicode, which just hacking at the apostrophes won't.

Comment: I was trying to escape `"` characters in json...common sense strikes again.

Comment: my python 2.7.2 doesnt serialize as such. "hello'world" is the product

Comment: @GabeRainbow the `'` doesn't need escaping. `"hello'world"` *is* a valid, safe JavaScript string literal.

Comment: @Droogans try storing it before you store it, a = json.dumps(sample), and then you can see that a = '"hello\'world"'

Comment: This works, but when i want to write such json to file, it removes the escapes, regardless of the ensure_ascii flag. Any ideas maybe?