# How to deal with single quote in xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a line where I check if a certain element by partial text exists on the page.

```
self.b.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), '%s')]" % item_text)
```

So it is possible that `item_text` has a single quote in the string. For example `"Hanes Men's Graphic "`.

It the becomes `self.b.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'Hanes Men's Graphic ')]")`

In that case i get the error:

```
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[contains(text(), 'Hanes Men's Graphic ')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
```

What operation should I perform on `item_text` before it is used in `self.b.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), '%s')]" % item_text)`

I know that I can use single quotes around the expression and use double quotes inside, but that's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: [You can check on how to escape quotes in python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3708167/3122133)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Escape Single Quotes in Python on Server to be used in Javascript on Client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708152/how-to-escape-single-quotes-in-python-on-server-to-be-used-in-javascript-on-clie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try as below :-

```
self.b.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), \"Hanes Men's Graphic\")]")
```

or

```
self.b.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(text(), "%s")]' % item_text)
```

or

```
self.b.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), \"%s\")]" % item_text)
```

Hope it will work..:)

Answer (score 2):

It might be that the xpath implementation won't allow double quotes for the string so you'll need to do something like

```
if (item_text.find("'")):
    item_text= item_text.replace("'", "', \"'\", '")
    item_text= "concat('" + item_text+ "')"
else:
    item_text = "'" + item_text + "'"

self.b.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), %s)]" % item_text)
```