# Handling single quotes in pytest parameter string

Tags: python, pytest

Have one pytest parameter having single quote in the string value. For example,

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'message1, code, message2', [
    ('test_exception_message', 'error_code_example', ''apples' are in the 'basket'')])

message2 = 'apples' are in the 'basket'
```

How to handle the quotes? Thanks.

Comment: Just use double quotes for the parameter, e.g. `"'apples' are in the 'basket'"`. Or you could escape them: `'\'apples\' are in the \'basket\''`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708152/how-to-escape-single-quotes-in-python-on-a-server-to-be-used-in-javascript-on-a

Comment: It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
message2 = "'apples' are in the 'basket'"
```

use double quotes or escape using

```
'\'apples\' are in the \'basket\''
```